# Android: Find view object by its ID if its not defined in XML

Tags: java, android, view

I have custom view object array that I created it progrmmatically. 
I got Id of one of this views by using `view.getId()` method.

```
int ID = MyView[0].getId;
```

In this situation how can I get my object by using this id? Like `findViewById(id)` method.
I tried this:

```
MyView v = (MyView) findViewById(ID);
```

but didn't work.

Comment: it has no sense,  why do you want to findViewById if you already have that View in your array?

Comment: Getting id and finding view are different methods. When I needto find view I have only ID, but I don't know which element of array is this

Comment: use a Map then: Map<Integer,  View>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is bad idea.
if u want use android native views search, u need declarate they in xml.

But if u really need to go this way, then:

```
View v = new View(context);

int savedId = v.getId;

View[] array = new View[lenght];

array[savedId] = v;
```

and then u get it someweare:

```
View anotherViewReference = array[savedId];
```